# How to check string for null and assign its value in the same line

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, nullreferenceexception

If I have a datatable which has a one row ,How to check the field for not null to avoid the exception and assign its value in the same line ?

```
txt_objective.Text = dtReqMas.Rows[0]["objective"].ToString().Trim();
```

Now I want to check `dtReqMas.Rows[0]["objective"]` for `null` 
  and set `txt_objective.Text = String.Empty;` if it was null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following conditional operator:

```
txt_objective.Text = dtReqMas.Rows[0].IsNull("objective") 
                     ? String.Empty : dtReqMas.Rows[0].Field<string>("objective");
```

Comment: I make the following check first
`if (dtReqMas != null && dtReqMas.Rows.Count > 0)
                {}`

Comment: @just_name. then you don't need to check if `dtReqMas.Rows.Count == 0`. I have removed it.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
txt_objective.Text = (dtReqMas.Rows[0]["objective"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: This is fine. You could also use `Field` to prevent the ugly parenthesis and `ToString`: `dtReqMas.Rows[0].Field<string>("objective") ?? string.Empty;`

Answer (score 1):

I think, this may helpful for you:

```
txt_objective.Text = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtReqMas.Rows[0]
["objective"].ToString()) ? string.Empty : dtReqMas.Rows[0]
["objective"].ToString().Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
txt_objective.Text = (dtReqMas!=null && dtReqMas.Rows.count>0 && !string.isNullOrEmpty(dtReqMas.Rows[0]["objective"])?dtReqMas.Rows[0]["objective"].ToString():string.Empty;
```